# Testing a Spring WebListener

Tags: java, spring

I have a class annotated with @WebListener, extending ServletContextListener that another class I'm testing relies on having executed. When I test manually (i.e. running in Tomcat) it works, but within my JUnit test the @WebListener class is never executed. I'm assuming that I need to add something to my configuration to get it to execute, but I'm not sure what. Or do I need to run it manually in the the test?

EDIT:
Here's the basics of the class

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // Retrieve spring application context
    ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
    springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I've added to my test class:

```
@Before
public void mockInit() {
    MockServletContext mockContext = new MockServletContext();
    new MyListener().contextInitialized(new ServletContextEvent(mockContext));
}
```

But the `springContext` variable in `contextInitialized` is null.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing a couple of things. 1st, my test class didn't have @WebAppConfiguration

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClassAbcTest extends TestBase {
  ...
}
```

Second, I needed to set the root application context:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

@Before
public void mockInit() {
  MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext();
  mockServletContext.setAttribute(
    WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webAppContext);
  new MyListener().contextInitialized(new ServletContextEvent(
    mockServletContext));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I accidentally found an answer to this that isn't shown here.

I'm using an Embedded Apache FTP Server in my Spring Boot app that is initialised by a `@WebListener`

The Web Listener class was being missed and no FTP Connections possible during Junit tests.

The following annotation fixed it

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

I'd hope this answer helps anyone who stumbles across this page the same way it helped me.